# How to display the list of available networks without the mouse?

Tags: windows-8

I'm a great believer of keyboard control and I've been wondering how to pull out the list of available networks in Windows 8.

At the moment, I click on the symbol of "steps" and the list will pop out on the right. How can I do that without the mouse, only using the keyboard?

Comment: I would just pin a shortcut to the `Network Control Pannel` applet.

Comment: And how do I click that shortcut without a mouse? I was hoping for a generic *Win + C* (but instead of charms folding out, I'd fold out the other panes). Doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Tab to the "Steps", or you can invoke the `netsh wlan show network` from a command prompt.

Comment: Oh, right. A bit to many tab steps to get there but when the muscle memory gets used to a series of key presses, that might be something. Thanks!